# Question on X_train data formatting

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, regression

I want to train a model to approximate the probability of an event between two objects based on previous occurrences. My input training data are the parameters (six in total) of the pairs that have taken part in a past event and the output training data are the computed probability of the event. So one case would be:

**X_train**:

```
param1_obj1,param2_obj2
param2_obj1,param2_obj2
..., ...
param6_obj1,param6_obj2
```

**Y_train**:

`probability of event`

My idea is to try to train a neural network and compare it with other models

My question is: How should I format the inputs to feed them to the network properly? Would feeding the (6,2) array work?

Comment: Its not clear to me what your „pairs“ are. I think a (6,2) shape should work. But if you also want to train other models and compare results, you will need to find an alternative encoding anyway. So my instinct would be to look for an alternative „1D“ encoding.

Comment: My pairs are arrays themselves so my first input would be X[0] = [vector1,vector2]. So the X training set is (n_samples,6,2)